# How to add the results of applying a function to an existing data frame?

Tags: r, tidyverse, confidence-interval, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the confidence intervals of some rates.
I am using tidyverse and epitools to calculate CI from Byar's method.

I am almost certainly doing something wrong.

```
library (tidyverse)
library (epitools)


# here's my made up data

DISEASE = c("Marco Polio","Marco Polio","Marco Polio","Marco Polio","Marco Polio",
            "Mumps","Mumps","Mumps","Mumps","Mumps",
            "Chicky Pox","Chicky Pox","Chicky Pox","Chicky Pox","Chicky Pox")
YEAR = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,
         2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,
         2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015)
VALUE = c(82,89,79,51,51,
          79,91,69,89,78,
          71,69,95,61,87)
AREA =c("A", "B","C")

DATA = data.frame(DISEASE, YEAR, VALUE,AREA)


# this is a simplification, I have the population values in another table, which I've merged 
# to give me the dataframe I then apply pois.byar to.
DATA$POPN = ifelse(DATA$AREA == "A",2.5,
              ifelse(DATA$AREA == "B",3,
                     ifelse(DATA$AREA == "C",7,0)))


# this bit calculates the number of things per area
rates<-DATA%>%group_by(DISEASE,AREA,POPN)%>%
  count(AREA)
```

Then if I want to calculate CI I thought this would work

```
rates<-DATA%>%group_by(DISEASE,AREA,POPN)%>%
  count(AREA) %>%
  mutate(pois.byar(rates$n,rates$POPN))
```

but i get

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1.
```

This however works:

```
pois.byar(rates$n,rates$POPN)
```

It seems daft to then say: "turn the results of the pois.byar function into a dataframe and then merge back to the original". I may have tried that just to get some data.... I don't want to do that. It's not the right way to do things.

Any advice gratefully received. 
I think it's a fairly basic problem. And indicative of my not sitting and learning but trying to do things as I go.

Here's what I want
Disease Year    n   area    popn    x   pt  rate    lower   upper   conf.level

Comment: `pois.byvar` [returns a `data.frame`](https://rdrr.io/cran/epitools/src/R/pois.byar.R). How do expect to "integrate" that into your existing `data.frame`? Can you show your expected output?

Comment: At the moment I have a row for Marco polio for area A. I'd like a data frame with the n, the popn, and then the output of pois.byar on the same row.

Comment: I'd have thought the pipe and mutate to add pois.byar would do this. But it seems not to.

Comment: `pois.byar` returns a `data.frame` so `mutate` will not accept that unless you wrap it in a `list`.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what your expected output is supposed to me. Your comment does not really help. Best to *explicitly* include your expected output for the sample data you give.

The issue here is that [`pois.byvar` returns a `data.frame`](https://rdrr.io/cran/epitools/src/R/pois.byar.R). So in order for `mutate` to be able to use the output of `pois.byvar` we need to store the `data.frame`s in a `list`.

Here is a tidier version of your code

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA %>%
    mutate(POPN = case_when(
        AREA == "A" ~ 2.5,
        AREA == "B" ~ 3,
        AREA == "C" ~ 7,
        TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
    group_by(DISEASE,AREA,POPN) %>%
    count(AREA) %>%
    mutate(res = list(pois.byar(n, POPN)))
```

This creates a column `res` which contains the `data.frame` output of `pois.byar`.

Or perhaps you'd like to `unnest` the `list` column to expand entries into different columns?

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA %>%
    mutate(POPN = case_when(
        AREA == "A" ~ 2.5,
        AREA == "B" ~ 3,
        AREA == "C" ~ 7,
        TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
    group_by(DISEASE,AREA,POPN) %>%
    count(AREA) %>%
    mutate(res = list(pois.byar(n, POPN))) %>%
    unnest()
## A tibble: 9 x 10
## Groups:   DISEASE, AREA, POPN [9]
#  DISEASE     AREA   POPN     n     x    pt  rate  lower upper conf.level
#  <fct>       <fct> <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 Chicky Pox  A       2.5     1     1   2.5 0.4   0.0363 1.86        0.95
#2 Chicky Pox  B       3       2     2   3   0.667 0.133  2.14        0.95
#3 Chicky Pox  C       7       2     2   7   0.286 0.0570 0.916       0.95
#4 Marco Polio A       2.5     2     2   2.5 0.8   0.160  2.56        0.95
#5 Marco Polio B       3       2     2   3   0.667 0.133  2.14        0.95
#6 Marco Polio C       7       1     1   7   0.143 0.0130 0.666       0.95
#7 Mumps       A       2.5     2     2   2.5 0.8   0.160  2.56        0.95
#8 Mumps       B       3       1     1   3   0.333 0.0302 1.55        0.95
#9 Mumps       C       7       2     2   7   0.286 0.0570 0.916       0.95
```

Comment: Just trying to edit the question to include desired format.

Comment: UNNEST. That's exactly what I want. THANK YOU.